# Can I replicate the table header when a table keep on in more pages?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following situation creating a PDF with iTextSharp.

I have some pages that contains some tables. It could be happen that a table begin in a page and keep on in the following page.

I want to know if, when a table keep on in the following page, is it possible to "replicate" the table header in the new page.

For example if a table begin in the page 1 and keep on in the table 2 I want have the following situation:

The table begin with its header in page 1 and keep on in page 2 so at the beginning of page 2 I have again the table header. Something like happen with table in Microsoft Word.

Can I do something like it?

Tnx

Comment: You really don't like to read documentation, do you?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something called "repeating table headers". You can find some examples on the official iText site on the page for the keyword [PdfPTable > header rows](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=187).

For instance, if you have an instance of `PdfPTable` named `table`, and the first two rows you've been adding are actually the header, then you can define them as header rows like this:

```
table.setHeaderRows(2);
```

If you want the C# version of the examples taken from my book, you can find them [here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178): http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04

These examples show you that the syntax in C# is slightly different, but still easy:

```
table.HeaderRows = 1;
```

In this line, we tell the `table` that the first row is a header row that should be repeated.